# How to return something from a callback function

Tags: javascript, java, callback

I'm trying to send a string from a callback, however this seems not working at all.

There is no output at all, using the code below.

```
    public void discoverPeers(final Callback callback) {
        manager.discoverPeers(channel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                callback.invoke("true");

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int reasonCode) {
                callback.invoke("false");

            }
        });
```

```
    WifiDirect.discoverPeers((success) => {
        console.log(success);
      })
```

The callback should invoke the string "true" or "false" back to the caller of the function.

Comment: Option 1: make the caller pass in a callback the same way you pass a callback to `discoverPeers`. Option 2: wait for the result of `discoverPeers`, e.g. by adding a `CompletableFuture`, `CountdownLatch`, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @luk2302 , I'm more interested of your suggestion(option 1), however i'm quite confuse on how to implement it. Can you advise? I understand now a little regarding the callback which will return an output once there is an output, that is why i'm having a no return at the moment. I tried using a settimeout, however there is still no good result. I believe this is a asynchronous callback issue.

Answer (score -1):

Couldn't you just simply call callback(string)? Because the callback method is passed as reference, you can use it as a function.

You need also to check the callback object visibility, you create a new instance of **WifiP2pManager.ActionListener**, so the callback method could be undefined inside your overrides methods.

Comment: Calling the callback early defeats the purpose of it being a callback. And he does not need to worry about any visibility, `callback` will always be visible in the two methods, otherwise it would not compile.

Answer (score -1):

The code is working actually, confirming it by moving all the codes to a new file. is a cache responsible for this?